# Baldi - Stochastic Calculus - Show a stopping time as a.s. finite

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, solution-verification, stopping-times

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from *Paolo Baldi - Stochastic Calculus - an introduction through theory and exercises*, Exercise 5.20

> Let $(B_t)_t$ a Brownian motion and for $\mu>0$, let $X_t= B_t + \mu t$.
>
> Let $a,b>0$ and $\tau$ be the exit time of $(X_t)_t$ from the interval $]-a,b[$.
>
> Show that $\tau$ is a.s. finite.

**My attempt**:

The solutions says just "by the iterative logarithm law", but I've not had that topic in the lectures, so I'll try an approach "by hand", using just the definition of my stopping time $\tau$ and the  law of the Brownian motion.

$$P(\tau>t) = \\P(X_t \in ]-a,b[) =\\ P(B_t + \mu t \in ]-a,b[) = \\ P(B_t \in ]-a - \mu t, b - \mu t[ ) = \\ P(B_1 \in ]\frac{-a-\mu t}{\sqrt{t}},\frac{b-\mu t}{\sqrt{t}}[)$$

The last probability equals $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{ \frac{-a-\mu t}{\sqrt{t}}}^{,\frac{b-\mu t}{\sqrt{t}}} e^{-x^2/2} dx$$

Now, since $P(\tau = \infty) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(\tau >t) = \lim_t  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{ \frac{-a-\mu t}{\sqrt{t}}}^{,\frac{b-\mu t}{\sqrt{t}}} e^{-x^2/2} dx =0 $

I conclude that $\tau$ is a.s. finite, where in the last equality I used the fact that the integrand is $C^{\infty}$, and since the function does not explodes as the integration interval becomes smaller and smaller, I can conclude.

**Is it okay?**

Comment: Your first step is wrong. $\tau >t$ is not the same as $X_t \in ]-a,b[$.

Comment: Sorry but I can't figure out why it's not the same. $\{\tau > t \}$ means that at time $t$ I am still in the interval... @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: That is only a one way inclusion. $\tau >t$ implies that the process is still inside the interval at time $t$ but the converse is not true. To say that $P(A)=P(B)$ you must prove that $A =B$, nut just $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out.So actually it just holds that $P(\tau > t) \leq P(X_t \in ]-a,b[)$ and my argument fails... or is there some way to fix it? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Actually there is no elementary proof of this.

Comment: But I know from theory that  $-\infty = \liminf_t B(t) \leq \limsup_t B(t) = \infty$, can't I use this to conclude that I will hit level $-a$ or level $b$ at some time?

Comment: If you know this result, yes,you can conclude that $\tau <\infty $ a.s..

Comment: Great, thanks;) 
Actually, I have in mind another way: I know that by OST I can get (using the martingale $(B_t^2 -t)_t$) that $E[\tau] = ab$, which shows that $\tau$ is actually integrable.

Comment: Now my really last question is: how can I see that $E[\tau] < \infty$ implies $\tau < \infty$ a.s. ?

I think $E[\tau] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(\tau>t)dt$, but then I don't know how to proceed @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KaviRamaMurthy already pointed out, your reasoning is not correct since the first "=" in your calculation fails to hold.

Here is one possible approach: It holds that $$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{B_t}{t} = 0 \quad \text{a.s.};$$ there are several ways to show this convergence, e.g. using (a variant of) the strong law of large numbers or the law of iterated logarithm. If $\mu>0$, then the process $X_t := B_t+\mu t$ satisfies

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{X_t}{t}= \mu>0 \quad \text{a.s.},$$

in particular,

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} X_t = \infty \quad \text{a.s.}$$

Since $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has continuous sample paths (with probability $1$), this means that exit time from any interval $(-\infty,b)$ is finite a.s. for each $b>0$. Hence, $\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty)=1$.

Another approach: The exit time $\sigma:=\inf\{t>0;B_t \geq b\}$ is finite with probability $1$. Since $X_t \geq B_t$, it follows that $\inf\{t>0;X_t \geq b\}$ is finite almost surely, and so is $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks! As I wrote in the comment,I could also use the martingale $(B_t^2 - t)_t$ an d by OST showing that $E[\tau] = ab$, hence it's integrable.


But $$P(\tau = \infty) = \lim_t P(\tau>t)$$ and since $$P(\tau > t) \leq \frac{E[\tau]}{t}=\frac{ab}{t} \rightarrow 0$$ I have that it's a.s. finite


Is everything okay ?

Comment: @andereBen Yes, it's okay.

Comment: Thanks for the check!