# $t \wedge \tau \uparrow \tau$ also if $\tau$ is not a.s. finite?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, almost-everywhere

I need a check on the following reasoning, that happens everytime I do an exercise about the stopping theorem.

---

Let $\tau$ be a stopping time w.r.t some filtration

Usual in the exercises about the optional stopping theorem I read:

$$ t \wedge \tau \uparrow \tau$$ And that's true if $\tau$ is a.s. finite.

---

**BUT** **if $\tau$  not a.s. finite**, can I still say $t \wedge \tau \uparrow \tau$?

I can note that if $\tau = \infty$ a.s., then for every $ t \in \mathbb{R}$ I have $t \wedge \tau =t$ and hence taking the limit I just can say that $$\lim_t t \wedge \tau = \infty$$ (which is a.s. the value of $\tau$)

All in all, I would say that it's true that $t \wedge \tau \uparrow \tau$ **also if $\tau$ is NOT a.s. finite**

Is it correct or am I missing something?

Comment: It is correct. You are not missing anything.

Comment: Thanks for your check @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: If it's not a problem for you, could you give also a check on this question of yesterday? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509324/baldi-stochastic-calculus-show-a-stopping-time-as-a-s-finite